# Vector/array of strings in MatLab

Tags: string, matlab

I want to create a container (array, vector, ... I don't perfectly know the difference between these in Matlab) of strings. I want to use it for display purposes and printing to files mainly. In C++ I would have something like:

```
std::vector<std::string> str;
str.push_back( "Test1" );
str.push_back( "Test2" );
str.push_back( "Test3" );

for( unsigned int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++ )
{
    printf( "%s\n", str[i].c_str() );
}
```

My question being: How can I achieve something similar in Matlab, or is it even possible. I've tried a few things I've found here and there but nothing works. Here are the things I tried:

```
str = ['Test1' 'Test2' 'Test3'];

str = ['Test1', 'Test2', 'Test3'];

str = ['Test1'; 'Test2'; 'Test3'];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `{` and `}` (cell arrays), otherwise you'll just concatenate strings.

```
str = {'test1', 'test2', 'LongerTestString'};

for ii = 1:length(str);
    disp(str{ii});
end
```

Comment: strings are arrays of characters, a cell array can contain multiple arrays (of different length), thus it can contain multiple strings. A matrix can also contain strings (of the same length) in its rows/columns, but a cell array is much better suited imo.

Comment: @GuntherStruyf I have adapted my answer to illustrate that.

Comment: yeah, the answer is fine, I just wanted to explain how the data is stored and what the options are when working with strings/characters.

Answer (score 0):

A complement to Nick answer (because cellfun are fun :)):

```
str = {'test1', 'test2', 'LongerTestString'};
cellfun(@disp, str)
```

Comment: I agree with you that they are fun, however they can be hard to debug.